# how can I create function from java to objective-c

Tags: java, objective-c

I'm a fresh IOS developer, and facing a problem in encryption and decryption.

decrypt code(java)

```
        byte[] keyPass = pass.getBytes("ASCII");
        byte[] aesIV = new byte[16];
        byte[] Decryptdata = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        System.arraycopy(Decryptdata, 0, aesIV, 0, 16);
        byte[] data = new byte[Decryptdata.length - 16];
        System.arraycopy(Decryptdata, 16, data, 0, dataToDecrypt.length - 16);
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyPass, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(aesIV);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, ivSpec);
        Text = new String(cipher.doFinal(data), "UTF-8");
```

encrypt code(java)

```
        byte[] keyPass = pass.getBytes("ASCII");
        final Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyPass, "AES");
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        byte[] byteMessage = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(byteMessage);
        byte[] ivByte = cipher.getIV();

        byte[] bytesTotal = new byte[ivByte.length+cipherText.length];
        System.arraycopy(ivByte, 0, bytesTotal, 0, ivByte.length);
        System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, bytesTotal, ivByte.length, cipherText.length);
        encyoted = Base64.encodeToString(bytesTotal, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

How can I create encrypt and decrypt in objective-c?

Comment: 1. Provide the encrypted data, decrypted data and IV as hex. 2. Use a full length key, AES supports 128, 192 & 256 bit keys. 3. We will wait for you to do your job, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you need to call java function or create objective-C function to decrypt java code ? @k.tan

Answer (score 0):

"how can i create function from java to objective-c"

For iOS use [Common Crypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Study, write code and debug. Repeat as necessary.